# EasyMock - expect anyObject except some

Tags: easymock, verify

Let's say I have a method like this:

```
foo (A a, B b)
```

I want to set expectation so that `anyObject` is expected except some, like the imaginary code below:

```
expect(mockedObject).foo(anyObject(A.class), anyObject(B.class)).andReturn(something).anyTimes();
expect(mockedObject).foo(new A("1"), new B("1")).andReturn(something).times(0);
expect(mockedObject).foo(new A("2"), new B("2")).andReturn(something).times(0);
expect(mockedObject).foo(new A("3"), new B("3")).andReturn(something).times(0);
```

However there is no `times(0)` in EasyMock. I can create a chain of `EasyMock.or()` and `EasyMock.not()` but it's going to be dirty when there are a lot of unexpected objects.

On Mockito I can easily specify

```
verify(mockedObject, never()).foo(new A("1"), new B("1"));
```

What's the easiest way on EasyMock to do the same thing as above?

Answer (score 1):

It is something missing indeed.

Right now, the easier is to `capture()` all your parameters and then check that no invalid permutation was used.

Comment: To my understanding with capture we can exclude invalid single values but we cannot exclude combinations. For example let's say we expect foo(new A("1"), new B("2")) but we don't expect foo(new A("1"), new B("1")). We shouldn't say not to expect new A("1").

Comment: Yes. But it you use 2 captures, parameters will be captured in order in both.